# Math formula for transforming from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, mathematics, formula

Is there any math formula for transforming from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 ?
i want to implement it in php code

Comment: I don't have the maths handy for the 4326 -> 3857 case (see http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/web_mercator/(U)%20NGA_SIG_0011_1.0.0_WEBMERC.pdf section A4.5 for the 3857 -> 4326 case which hopefully you can invert), but http://sourceforge.net/projects/proj4php/ might be a better approach in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projection `EPSG:3857` uses the method `EPSG:1024` for Forward and Reverse calculations.

The method is fully documented at [Geomatics Guidance Note No 7, part 2](https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf)

There's an mathematical example at page 40 where you can use to cross-reference your code.

17/11/2020 EDIT: The link to the above documentation from times to times, gets broken as things evolve. If that happens please feel free to update it as necessary.

Comment: the given link in the answer is broken

Comment: https://epsg.io/1024-method is another helpful resource

Answer (score 2):

I got a C# code for using in unity engine.

Here the code below :

```
public static double[] latLonToMeters(double lat, double lon)
{
    //Debug.Log(Mathd.Tan((90d + lat) * Mathd.PI / 720));
    //Debug.Log(Mathd.Tan((90d + lat) * Mathd.PI / 360d));
    double[] meters = new double[2];
    meters[0] = lat * originShift / 180d;
    meters[1] = Mathd.Log(Mathd.Tan((90d+lon) * Mathd.PI / 360d)) / (Mathd.PI / 180d);
    //meters[1] = Mathd.Log(5) / (Mathd.PI / 180d);
    meters[1] = meters[1] * originShift / 180d;
    return meters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CoordinateConverter {

    private static final double a = 6378137.0;


    public static Epsg4326Coordinate convertEpsg3857To4326(Epsg3857Coordinate epsg3857Coordinate) {
        // D = -N / a
        // φ = π / 2 – 2 atan(e ^ D)
        // λ = E / a

        var d = -epsg3857Coordinate.getY() / a;
        var phi = Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(d));
        var lambda = epsg3857Coordinate.getX() / a;
        var lat = phi / Math.PI * 180;
        var lon = lambda / Math.PI * 180;

        return new Epsg4326Coordinate(lon, lat);
    }


    public static Epsg3857Coordinate convertEpsg4326to3857(Epsg4326Coordinate epsg4326Coordinate) {
        // E = x = a * λ
        // N = y = a * ln[tan(π/4 + φ/2)]

        var lambda = epsg4326Coordinate.getLongitude() / 180 * Math.PI;
        var phi = epsg4326Coordinate.getLatitude() / 180 * Math.PI;
        var x = a * lambda;
        var y = a * Math.log(Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + phi / 2));

        return new Epsg3857Coordinate(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code (may need to switch lat and long depending on your use case):

```php
function convert4326to3857($x, $y)
{
    return [
        $x / 180 * 20037508.34,
        log(tan(($y + 90) / 360 * pi())) * 111319.490778 / pi() * 180,
    ];
}
```

Comment: This didn't give the correct output for me (off by a lot). Is your calculation correct?