# Converting from esoteric coordinate systems to EPSG:4326 WGS 84

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, convert, ajax

I have a shapefile with coordinates in the "EPSG:3081 NAD83 / Texas State Mapping System" coordinate system. I'd like to be able to convert these to EPSG:4326 WGS 84 and it's not clear how.

https://epsg.io/transform calls https://epsg.io/trans?x=1137180.95833637&y=958229.501643337&s_srs=3081&t_srs=4326 via AJAX and I tried calling that with a for each of the 1,000+ coordinates that I have but it seems like that URL throttles requests.

Comment: I'm no expert but since the link you provide list the coor transform in x and y you couldn't just apply it directly to the data? Never had to do manual conversions but that seems simple enough to test.

Comment: If there's a EPSG code for it, it doesn't seem all that esoteric to me. It's perfectly reasonable that epsg.io would rate-limit their server -- It's their server after all. Since there are so many other tools that support deprojection with transform, it doesn't seem like this is really any challenge.

Comment: Since 3081 is available in QGIS it should be possible with QGIS unless I am missing the point

Comment: @Alrl - you don't just multiply the latitude and longitude by some constant value to get the new latitude / longitude in a new coordinate system. If it was that easy then maybe you should reply to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325551/17847

Comment: @MDollinger - I'll have to check that out - I didn't know QGIS could do that.

Comment: you can also use ogr2ogr from the command line to change the projection. [This article](https://datawanderings.com/2018/08/23/changing-dataset-projection-with-ogr2ogr/) explains how.

Comment: @Llaves - that's awesome - I didn't know that - thanks! That was the most convenient as I was already using ogr2ogr to do the import.

Comment: This question already had something similar if you wanted to do it manually https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133861/converting-between-wgs84-and-nad83

Answer (score 2):

The EPSG:3081 NAD83 / Texas State Mapping System is supported by [MyGeodata Cloud Converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) so you can upload your Shapefile there, set EPSG:3081 as input coordinate system (if it is not recognized automatically), select output coordinate system to EPSG:4326 WGS 84 and choose output format - you can leave ESRI Shapefile or for example extract coordinates to CSV file...